# How to multiply each column by all the columns of another df, obtaining a multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need to split each column according to percentages found in another df. E.g.:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> things = ['some thing', 'another thing']
>>> 
>>> amount = pd.DataFrame({2019: [10, 20], 2020: [100, 200]}, index=things)
>>> amount
               2019  2020
some thing       10   100
another thing    20   200
>>> 
>>> split = pd.DataFrame({'first': [0.2, 0.9], 'second': [0.8, 0.1]}, index=things)
>>> split
               first  second
some thing       0.2     0.8
another thing    0.9     0.1
>>> 
>>> result = amount ??? split  # how to do this?
>>> result
               2019         2020       
              first second first second
some thing        2      8    20     80
another thing    18      2   180     20
```

How can I do this in pandas in one simple shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat()` with list comprehension for cross products of the (2 x 2) Series from the 2 dataframes, as follows:

**2 list comprehensions:**

`[amount[i] * split[j] for i in amount.columns for j in split.columns]` for cross product of the (2 x 2) Series

`[(x, y) for x in amount.columns for y in split.columns]` for column index

```
result = pd.concat([amount[i] * split[j] for i in amount.columns for j in split.columns],
                   keys=[(x, y) for x in amount.columns for y in split.columns], axis=1)




print(result)

               2019          2020       
              first second  first second
some thing      2.0    8.0   20.0   80.0
another thing  18.0    2.0  180.0   20.0
```

If you are sure the resulting values will be integers and want the values be integers, you can further convert its type by `.astype(int)`:

```
result = pd.concat([amount[i] * split[j] for i in amount.columns for j in split.columns],
                   keys=[(x, y) for x in amount.columns for y in split.columns], axis=1).astype(int)




print(result)

               2019         2020       
              first second first second
some thing        2      8    20     80
another thing    18      2   180     20
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems a straight forward approach. I was hoping for a "more pandasy" solution (a pandas function/method generating the result directly). But if there is no such function, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Apparently it looks like using list comprehension but it actually relies heavily on Pandas features. First of all, you have to base on the 2 source daraframes have the same row index. Otherwise you can't multiply the 2 Series pair and get the desired colum-wise product. You have to know how the multi-level column index is built based on tuples of column pairs. You have to know also where you can get the colum list from Pandas. Also which Pandas function and parameters to combine them all. Actually, I also tried other functions like .merge() with how='cross', apply() etc. but didn't work